# Querying unique items by date

Tags: c#, linq

I am querying TFS builds and I want to select projects where the latest built was in 2015 or earlier.

```
var builds = buildserver.QueryBuilds(source);
var oldBuilds = builds.Where(b => b.FinishTime.Year < 2016).ToList();
```

The problem is the variable "builds" contains multiple builds per project. So ProjectA could contain builds in 2015, 2016, 2017.

How can I get unique projects where the last built was in 2015 using linq?

Comment: you talk about builds and projects, but in your code only see builds, is there a project property in `build` class, or?

Comment: Hi, IBuildDetail is the object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetail(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Yes, the project property is under build.BuildDefinition.Name

Comment: In my case the name of the project is the name of the builddefinition

Comment: Can you group by project names and then select  .OrderByDesc().First()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var oldBuilds = builds.GroupBy(allBuilds => allBuilds.BuildDefinition)
                      .Where(projectBuilds => projectBuilds.All(
                          project => project.FinishTime.Year< 2016))
                      .Select(projectBuilds => projectBuilds.OrderByDescending(
                          project => project.FinishTime).FirstOrDefault());
```

This will return the latest build of all projects that haven't been built since 2015.

Comment: Thanks @InBetween . I also want to print out the last timestamp. I guess have to order the group by date and take the first row?

Comment: Hi @InBetween the .OrderByDescending is in the context of the GroupBy so only the Key property is available in the lambda.

Comment: @doorman Sorry, writing code form a cell phone is sometimes tricky ;). It should be ok now.